# Error when trying to cast db query to string

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to extract one integer from the database but am getting errors

My code in the controller is:

```
        Dim SeqNumQuery = From a In db.RequestedServices
                          Where a.RequestedServiceId = id
                          Select a.StationId

        Dim StationId As Integer = SeqNumQuery.ToString
```

And error is:

Range variable 'StationId' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression.

Comment: Why are you comverting StationId to string and assigning it to an integer variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that your variable, `StationId`, is being declared somewhere already within the same scope. Try changing to:

```
Dim SeqNumQuery = From a In db.RequestedServices
                          Where a.RequestedServiceId = id
                          Select a.StationId

StationId = SeqNumQuery.ToString
```

But look into what the other variable is being used for. If you need it, use something other than `StationId` for your variable name, for example `RequestedServicesStationId`.

More information regarding this error:

[Range variable  hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763096%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

---

On a side note, I don't understand why you are using `.ToString` extension method. This won't cause your script to throw an exception, however I would recommend changing this to [`CInt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
StationId = CInt(SeqNumQuery)
```